# I have tamron di 70-300 for Nikon , will it fit a canon D 4000 body?

Tags: nikon

Will a tamron lens for Nikon fit a canon body

Comment: Using native lenses will usually give a better experience.

Comment: @xiota that is not even close to being helpful to community or the OP

Comment: @aaaaaa OP appears to be new to photography.  My earlier comment is intended to steer her away from adapted lenses, which at her stage, would serve merely as an exercise in fruatration.  If you feel that isn't helpful, you're free to write an answer or comment that would be.

Comment: Cross platform adapted lenses are one thing, which is what this question is about. But be careful not to throw the baby out with the bath water. Adapting an EF lens from the Canon EOS system to an EOS EF-M mount camera, or an EF-lens to an EOS RF mount camera is pretty much seamless. AF, aperture control, IS, and any other functionality the EOS lens has with an EF camera is retained when used via an EOS adapter with EF-M or RF cameras which also are EOS cameras.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I calculated in Euros. Dollar prices for all that kit seem to be a bit higher but at the same basic relation!)

There are actually such adapters, they will cost 25 bucks, however they will make a manual focus, manual aperture lens out of an AF lens. AF lenses tend to make very kludgy and disappointing MF lenses, especially on a consumer DSLR. So be sure that is what you want, if going that route.

This lens, while being positively reviewed in a lot of places, is currently on sale everywhere for prices a little over 100 bucks, while secondhand prices are not exactly below the bottom.

If you keep cameras of both brands, just getting a second copy might be better value for money. If you are changing systems, selling the Nikon copy and buying a canon dedicated one could have you all set for 50 bucks.